# Reset variable in a sequential case statement in verilog

Tags: variables, verilog, fpga, flags

I want to give only one strobe pulse of 2 clock cycles wide everytime a data is placed on the output. I am not able to implement the logic in verilog.Here is the pseudocode i have written

```
reg [1:0] step = 2'b00;
always @ (posedge clock)
begin    
case (switch)
1'b0 : begin        
       load data 1;
       flag <= 1;
   end
1'b0 : begin        
       load data 2;
       flag <= 1;
       end    
endcase

if (flag == 1)
case (step)
2'b00 : strobe high;
2'b01 : wait;
2'b10 : strobe low;
2'b11 : flag <=0;   
endcase 
end
```

If I do this the reg step is becoming 2'b11 after properly giving the strobe pulse after the first data, but I am not able to reset it to zero again for the second data, so when second time flag is set high the step variable only enters the last case. If I set step <= 2'b00 elsewhere the strobe output is constantly changing with each clock cycle. I want only one pulse.

Actual Code :

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test3(
input i_clock,
input i_switch,
output reg [7:0] o_data = 8'b00001111,
output reg o_strobe = 1'b0
);

reg flag = 1'b0;
reg [1:0] step = 2'b00;

always @ (posedge i_clock)
begin
  if (flag == 1'b0)
    begin
      case (i_switch)                                 
        1'b0  :  begin
                   o_data [7:0] <= 32'b00000000;
                   flag <= 1'b1;
                 end
        1'b1  :  begin
                   o_data [7:0] <= 32'b11111111;
                   flag <= 1'b1;
                 end
      endcase
    end
else if (flag == 1)
      begin
        case (step)
          2'b00  :  begin
                      o_strobe <= 1'b1;
                      step <= 2'b01;
                    end
          2'b00  :  begin
                      step <= 2'b10;
                    end
          2'b10  :  begin
                      o_strobe <= 1'b0;
                      step <= 2'b11;
                    end
          2'b11  :  begin
                      flag <= 1'b0;
                      // step <= 2'b00;
                    end
       endcase
    end
  end
endmodule
```

**Waveforms:**
No strobe on 2nd data, step <= 2'b00 commented

http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c315/soumyabumba/strobe_zpsc342b740.gif

[image: photo strobe_zpsc342b740.gif]

Continuous toggling strobe, step <= 2'b00 uncommented

[image: Strobe toggling photo pulse_strobe_zps8a1a5fb4.gif]

http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c315/soumyabumba/pulse_strobe_zps8a1a5fb4.gif

Comment: Please post your actual code, not pseudocode. Also try to look at the waveform in a simulator to debug.

Comment: Hi Tim, I simulated it in Isim. I will post the actual code and the waveforms shortly. Thanks

Comment: Hi added the code and waveforms. Plz help me to solve this. I want a single strobe pulse after the second data.

Comment: Why does your `case(step)` have 2'b00 listed twice?

Comment: The case (step) is a sequential process to shape the strobe pulse in 4 clock cycles after flag bit is set high. After the process is completed i have to reset flag to 0 and step to 2'b00 so that if again data is changed and flag bit is set high in the case (switch) process, the case(step) process should be ready to shape the strobe again, a process which starts at setting the strobe high at step=2'b00.

Comment: Oh sorry...I didnt notice...It should be 2b'01.

Comment: I changed and simulated it again but no improvement. Same toggling waveform is coming.

Comment: If you add some more signals to the waveform you should be able to debug. Can you add `flag` and `step` to the debug and try to trace why they are not behaving as you expect?

Comment: I haven't added any internal variables in waveform window in ISim till now since I am new to verilog. I'll try it and let you know the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot Tim. I solved it and its only because of your helpful suggestion to add the flag and step waveforms. The main problem was that the `case(switch)` is getting executed on each clock cycle with the switch value of previous cycle and it is triggering the flag which is there under each statement. So I removed the `case(i_switch)` from `always @ (i_clock)` and put it separately in an `always @ (i_switch)` so that the `case(switch)` runs only when the switch is changed.

I am facing a minor problem though. Since I have added the `always@(i_switch)` block I am having doubts on initializing the `i_switch` input in the test bench file. If I initialize it before the global reset of 100# the o_data is starting as `00000000` instead of `00001111` i.e. the case statement started running even before the global reset completes. If i give i_switch as a stimulus after 100# a red line and a X is coming for `i_switch` for 100# indicating uninitialized input. I have attached the waveform and the solved code. Will there be any problem in implementation of this? Also I read somewhere all if statement must follow by else statement otherwise unwanted latching may occur, what can be written under `else (flag == 0)` condition under `always @(i_clock)`?

**Waveform :**

http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c315/soumyabumba/strobe_solved_zps72b65a42.png

**Solved Code:**

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test3(
input i_clock,
input i_switch,
output reg [7:0] o_data = 8'b00001111,
output reg o_strobe = 1'b0
);

reg flag = 1'b0;
reg [1:0] step = 2'b00;

always @ (i_switch)
begin
    case (i_switch)                                 
    1'b0  :  begin
               o_data [7:0] <= 32'b00000000;
               flag <= 1'b1;
             end
    1'b1  :  begin
               o_data [7:0] <= 32'b11111111;
               flag <= 1'b1;
             end
    endcase
end

always @ (posedge i_clock)
begin
if (flag == 1)
  begin
    case (step)
      2'b00  :  begin
                  o_strobe <= 1'b1;
                  step <= 2'b01;
                end
      2'b01  :  begin
                  step <= 2'b10;
                end
      2'b10  :  begin
                  o_strobe <= 1'b0;
                  step <= 2'b11;
                end
      2'b11  :  begin
                  flag <= 1'b0;
                  step <= 2'b00;
                end
   endcase
end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: @Tim Hi i am again having trouble with this. The above code simulates just fine but I found out it is cannot be synthesized since I am assigning the variable 'flag' in two different 'always' block. I am getting the error ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit test3 on signal flag; this signal is connected to multiple drivers. To resolve this I need to assign flag only under a single always block which brings me back to my original problem. I am not able to get any other logic to implement this. Is there any way to do this?